# Changing the cursor on a hold down?

Tags: jquery, html

So i want to change the cursor from

```
#sideBar ul li .template{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

to maybe cursor:move; when the user is dragging...is there something i can use in jQuery or html to make this happen you hold down the mouse button

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of changing the css in your javascript code, keep it to just changing one class, which will update your element with as many different things as you want. I added a :hover pseudo-class because I'm not sure if `cursor` works without it.

Also, live works for any element added in the future and bind does not.

Css:

```
#sideBar ul li .template{
 cursor:pointer;
}

#sideBar ul li .template.mouseDown:hover{
 cursor:auto; /* or whatever cursor */
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#sideBar ul li .template").live("mousedown", function () {
    $(this).addClass("mouseDown");
}).live("mouseup", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("mouseDown");
});
```

Comment: Just to add to those that find this. The .live() method is now depricated as of jQuery 1.7. You can use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in it's place.

Answer (score 2):

You can try binding a css change to the [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) event using jQuery. And then use mouseup() to change the cursor back when the user has finished dragging.

e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sideBar ul li .template').mousedown(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'move');
    });
    $('#sideBar ul li .template').mouseup(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can definitely do this.  The Jquery [.mouseDown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) function can be set as a handler, then you only need to change the css.  Heres an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aardvark/qrkDu/)

```
$('.someElement').mousedown(function()
{
   $(this).css('cursor', 'move');
});
$('.someElement').mouseup(function()
{ 
   $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to repeat essentially the same code others have posted, but a proper drag shouldn't be triggered on simply a mousedown event.

On mousedown you should flag a Possible Drag and save the mouse coordinates where the mousedown occurred, then attach a mousemove handler. (This way you don't constantly track mousemoves when you're only really interested in them during a drag)

The mousemove handler should change the CSS class of the dragged element only when the distance between the saved mousedown coordinates and the current mouse coordinates is greater than some delta.  This prevents every brief/accidental click from looking like a drag.

Finally, on drop (mouseup) then handle the drop event as desired, and clear the Possible Drag flag and the saved mousedown coordinates.

Watch an OS Desktop click-and-hold on an icon, without moving, then begin moving -- you'll see that this outline is how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
someFunc({
  onstart: function(){
     $(document.body).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
  },

  onstop: function(){
     $(document.body).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
  }
});
```

Where `onstart` must be triggered when the dragging starts, and `onstop` when it ends.

---

If you're creating a custom drag function, you could use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events:

```
$(el)
  .mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
  })
  .mouseup(function(){
    $(this).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
  });
```