# How can I hide (or change) the drag not allowed cursor during a dragging?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

hi.

I'm trying to find out how to hide the "drag not allowed" cursor during a drag operation.

I could be okay with changing it too, if removing isn't possible. I feel like I'm not getting something though, it sounds like an easy thing, doesn't it?

Here I've made a small fiddle for showing the issue: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dlofud/qLusfedc/61/)

```
box0.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
box0.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);
box0.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
box0.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
container.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
container.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
container.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);

function dragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
    setTimeout (() => {e.target.classList.add('boxh');}, 0);}
function dragend(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('boxh');
}
function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the cursor on a hold down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082195/changing-the-cursor-on-a-hold-down)

Comment: @Esszed, thanks for your suggestion, although I believe this doesn't cover my issue. I'd like to avoid JQuery, plus :hover works when the cursor moves over something, not simply during a drag, mmh. I'm not sure if I can convey the problem...

Comment: Does the cursor change applies only in in the grey target container or even outside of it?

Comment: If you don't care about what actual cursor you will have, you can use one of the `dropEffect` inside a `dragOver` function. Like this: `function dragOver(e){
e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
e.preventDefault();
}`

Comment: @Esszed The cursor change into the "drag not allowed" icon both when dragging it (just by dragging, not dropping) over the grey container and outside of it, basically everywhere, while I would simply like to have no cursor at all.

Comment: Edit: I've added your code: now, when dragging the cursor appearing is the one of the "copy" action, so the cursor _is_ changed, but I'd prefer to have no cursor at all, or to be able to choose a specific cursor. mmh.

Comment: After doing some research I am pretty sure that using the browser api for drag and drop won't allow you to do that. You would have to use jQuery (or other library or own code for drag and drop) for that.

Comment: Mmh, I see. Could you point me toward some JQuery code on this issue?

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/ check out jQueryUI documentation. It is quite easy with it. It has also own cursor option.

Comment: Maybe this is actually the only viable path, mmh. I've tried PointerLock too but, while it does hide the cursor pointer, it still seems to keep the "copy" cursor visible, which is still unwanted. (Plus, it moves the dragged object toward the center of the display).

Comment: And yet... Here, this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API#simple_example_walkthrough It does exactly what I'd like to do, though I don't know how to make it works with a div instead of a shape. :(

Comment: Also not sure about that. Alternatively you can use some other custom drag solution. For example check out [this](https://codepen.io/tp-n-zoubek/pen/BamdJBE) demo from w3s. I added cursor changes to the functions so it function roughly how you want it to.

Answer (score 10):

To prevent the forbidden cursor the `preventDefault()` also needs to go on the **target element (!!)** - preferably the entire **document**

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To hide the not-allowed cursor and make your drop zones valid you need to apply  preventDefault on both dragOver and dragEnter.

Once you have a valid drop zone you can change the cursor with e.dataTransfer.dropEffect to either "copy", "move", "link", "none". (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect)

Unfortunately doesn't seem like there's no-cursor option.

```
onDragOver={e => {
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    e.preventDefault()
}}
onDragEnter={e => {
    e.preventDefault()
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can answer this question (it's been more than a year), but I stumbled into this issue today, and I was surprised by how hard is to change the cursor while dragging an element using JS.

I tried to use `dataTransfer` object, the `dropEffect` property and the `dragEvent` event, and none of these worked for me (even following MDN Web Docs).

So, for those out there who are still struggling to change the cursor while dragging, try to do this (it worked for me):

**Summary Note**: Simply add a CSS class with `pointer-events` set to `none` to the elements you don't want the "not allowed" cursor to display.

```js
// Get the container
const file_container = document.querySelector("#file_container")

// Get the files
const files = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id='file']")

// Iterate each file
for (let file of files)
  {
    // Start to drag the file
    file.addEventListener("dragstart", (ev)=>{
      ev.target.classList.add("ds_awaiting_file")
    })

    // Allow drop by preventing dragover event
    file_container.addEventListener("dragover", (ev)=>{ev.preventDefault()})

    // Remove applied styles to the awaiting file
    document.addEventListener('dragend', ()=>{
      file.classList.remove("ds_awaiting_file")
    });
  }
```

```css
/* Problem Solver (select div's children) */
[data-id=file] *
{
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* General Style */
#file_container
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 160px 160px 160px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

[data-id=file]
{
  border: 2px solid #1E3050;
  padding: 12px 60px
}

.block
{
  background-color: #1E3050;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.ds_awaiting_file
{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="file_container">

  <div data-id="file" draggable="true">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <p>File_1</p>
  </div>

  <div data-id="file" draggable="true">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <p>File_2</p>
  </div>

  <div data-id="file" draggable="true">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <p>File_3</p>
  </div>

  <div data-id="file" draggable="true">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <p>File_4</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This will *hide the "drag not allowed" cursor during drag operation* **but** keep in mind that (in some browsers such as Google Chrome and Opera), borders and margins will still be considered as no-allowed elements.