# How to change cursor on dragging

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with changing the cursor during object dragging. I'm trying to figure out how to properly change the cursor at the moment of dragging.

I have a React component.
I tried to implement cursor change like this, but it doesn't work. With this implementation, the cursor doesn't change during dragging (it stays as the default crossed circle).

```
function App() {
  const dragTarget = useRef(null);

  function dragStartHandler(e) {
    dragTarget.current.style.cursor = 'move';
  }

  function dragEndHandler() {
    dragTarget.current.style.cursor = 'auto';
  }

  return (
    <div
   
      draggable
      onDragStart={dragStartHandler}
      onDragEnd={dragEndHandler}
      id="dragTarget"
      className="draggable-element"
    >
      Drag me!
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please help me understand how to manipulate cursor styles correctly during dragging. Thank you in advance.

I have already tried what was suggested in both answers, and it doesn't work for me
I am attaching screenshots
[image: My code after the suggested changes.]

Comment: I found a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050102/how-can-i-hide-or-change-the-drag-not-allowed-cursor-during-a-dragging), but there is no answer on how to change the cursor. In the suggested answers, the property e.dataTransfer.dropEffect is changed, and consequently, the cursor is changed through this. But there are more than 10 possible data values for the cursor property and only 4 for dropEffect. Is it really impossible to change the cursor using any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cursor style is not supported by most browsers. I think the cursor style of the element being dragged is determined by the browser and cannot be overridden by CSS or JavaScript.

A possible solution is to change the cursor style of the document body instead, which will affect the cursor style of the whole page. You can do this by adding the following lines to your code:

```
function dragStartHandler(e) {
document.body.style.cursor = 'move';
}

function dragEndHandler() {
document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work for me, the cursor doesn't change."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:active` to style this:

```
div {
   cursor: grab;
}

div:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

Comment: it's dosent work for me too