How to disable "not-allowed" cursoe while dragging an element
The add button adds a new card and the position of card changes with my drag and drop input. Whenever i drag the cursor changes to "no-change", i want the cursor to be "grabbing".
I tried setting the cursor to 'grab' in all ways possible but couldn't find the solution
Additionally, please let me know if my implementation of drag and drop functionality is a bad practice.
Image of the website
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
const Card = ({text}) => {

  const [position, setPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})
  const [prevPosition, setPrevPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false)

  const dragEndHandler = (e)=>{
    const currPosition = {x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY}
    const diff = {
      x: position.x + (currPosition.x - prevPosition.x),
      y: position.y + (currPosition.y - prevPosition.y)
    }
    
    setPosition(diff)
    setIsDragging(false)
  }

  const dragStartHandler = (e)=>{
    
    setPrevPosition({x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY})
    setIsDragging(true)
  }

  const cardStyle = {
    position: 'relative',
    left: `${position.x}px`,
    top: `${position.y}px`,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: '8px',
    padding: '8px',
    display: 'inline-block',
    cursor: 'grab'
  };

  return (
    <div  style={cardStyle} draggable onDragStart={dragStartHandler} onDragEnd={dragEndHandler}>
      {text}
    </div>
  )
}


export default Card


Whenever i drag the cursor changes to "no-change", i want the cursor to be "grabbing".
I tried setting the cursor to 'grab' in all ways possible but couldn't find the solution.
e.preventDefault() makes the the immovable defeating the entire point
Additionally, please let me know if my implementation of drag and drop functionality is a bad practice.

Did you checkout the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050102/how-can-i-hide-or-change-the-drag-not-allowed-cursor-during-a-dragging

Yeah they suggested to use e.preventDefault() but using that in my code makes the code not work at all
